# AEM search for files in DAM

Tags: aem, query-builder, dam

I want to search files in my DAM folder using querybuilder. In my test folder, I have 1 .pptx file (powerpoint) and 1 .png file (image).

But when I run the below query, I get 3 results:

```
1. <PPTX file>/jcr:content
2. <PPTX file>.jcr:content/subassets/slide1/jcr:content
3 <image file>/jcr:content
```

The query is:

```
path=/content/dam/my-folder
type=dam:AssetContent
p.limit=-1
```

Are there any other predicates available to restrict this to 2 results, (files only) ?

I've tried `"type=dam:Asset"`, but it gives 0 results. and `"type=nt:base"` gives 20 results

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the predicate `mainasset`. When you specify `mainasset=true` in your query it would ignore the subassets in the result. So, you can just search for type `dam:Asset` and specify the `mainasset` predicate as shown below.

```
path=/content/dam/my-folder
type=dam:Asset
mainasset=true
p.limit=-1
```

For more information on the list of available predicates in AEM, refer to this [user guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-predicate-reference.html).

Comment: This is perfect, just a note it will work on version 6.3 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Below AEM 6.3 -

Use `path.flat` predicate to narrow down the search to only the direct children and not the `subtree`.

```
path=/content/dam/we-retail/en/mahna
path.flat=true 
type=dam:AssetContent
```

You can also use `nodename` predicate to query node names with a specific file extension

```
path=/content/dam/we-retail/en/mahna
type=dam:Asset
group.1_nodename=*.pptx
group.2_nodename=*.JPG
group.p.or=true
```